# Providing different configuration file to ConfigurationSettingsReader constructor

Tags: c#, ioc-container, autofac

when I am trying to set my register configuration in some other file than app.config,
I try this solution:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac", "Other.config");
```

Unfortunatelly this does not work, I get info that "autofac" section could not be readed.

Here is my Other.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="autofac" type="Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler, Autofac.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>

  <autofac>
    <components>
      <component type="IoCConsoleApplication1.Car, IoCConsoleApplication1">
        <properties>
          <property name="Description" value="CIĘŻAROWY"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
    </components>
  </autofac>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" sku="Client"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas what is wrong here ?

Regards,
Lukasz

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go to bind to a custom app.config file:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE","c:\\custom.config");
```